# Is it possible to interact with a particular child view while ignoring all other siblings?

Tags: android

I am creating a small touch drawing app in Android using a FrameLayout, I have included three custom views which are drawing canvases. The 1st child in the stack has a white background, while the two children on top are transparent. I managed to get both drawing and erasing to function properly on all three layers.

It seems as if I am only able to draw on the child view that is at the top of the stack, which is layer 3. Using `layerx.bringToFront();` does not seem to solve my issue either, since I would like to keep the layers in their proper z-order.

Is it possible to draw on "Layer 2" that is centered between layers 1 and 3, with new paths going under layer 3 and on top of layer 1?

(I apologize if my explanation is somewhat unclear. I can provide an image if needed.)

Edit: here is an image clarifying my issue:
[L1, L2 and L3 points to Layers 1, 2, and 3 respectively, with "Bottom" in layer 1 being drawn in green, "mid" in layer 2 drawn in black, and "top" in layer 3 being drawn in purple.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g43bk.png)

This is the order I drew the text:

1. Layer 1 - green text
2. Layer 2 - black text
3. Layer 3 - purple text
4. Layer 2 - black line drawn at bottom

I would like it so that whenever I go back to Layer 2, new paths will be drawn over existing paths on layer 1, and under existing paths of layer 3. Is this possible?

The XML code shows the layout of the three custom child views:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.user.layerpaint.MainActivity">


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:id="@+id/frames">

    <com.example.user.layerpaint.DrawingView
        android:id="@+id/layer3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="@null"/>

    <com.example.user.layerpaint.DrawingView
        android:id="@+id/layer2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="@null"/>

    <com.example.user.layerpaint.DrawingView
        android:id="@+id/layer1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF"/>

</FrameLayout>
```